# General strategy for clearing a level in Fractal?

Tags: fractal

I don't appear to be very good at Fractal;

[image]

In fact, I frequently find myself in a position where I accidentally set off a chain reaction that clears half of the board, and the rest of the time I spend a notable amount of my limited moves pushing pieces that are already on the edge of the board off the board;

[image]

What sort of strategy should I use when playing this game to achieve the greatest success? Should I aim to make moves that push multiple pieces inwards? should I always go for the single piece moves that clear a section of the board? Should I take care not to push pieces off the board with my moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good strategy is to move pieces from the edges inwards NEXT TO other clusters. Look for clusters that might make out parts of blooms, and push blocks next to those.

Here are some examples of pushes that would give you blooms based on the picture you have there:
[image: Fractal 1]
[image: Fractal 2]

Pushing in the direction of the arrows would produce blooms at the circles, basically. Hope that helps somewhat.